# Language parameter is not working in TinyMCE - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am trying to use TinyMCE-React in the Japanese language. But an error has occurred by using the Language Parameter. Here is my code -

```
 <Editor
    apiKey="myAPIKEY"
    onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
    initialValue={content}
    init={{
      height: 500,
      menubar: false,
      plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table paste code help charcount"
      ],
      toolbar: "link unlink",
      language: "jp",
      content_style:
        "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }"
    }}
  />
```

I have downloaded the Japanese Language file from [TinyCloud Language Packages](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/language-packages/) and placed the folder into 'node-modules/tinymce/langs/'.

The error is -

> Failed to load language: jp from url https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/zfcdl0u4w24n4pn00cstkriz1y8tw1wagp0v9b2c2qqc60qf/tinymce/5.10.4-130/langs/jp.js

So, now I am looking for a way to use the editor in Japanese. Does anybody can help me with this language customization?

Answer (score 0):

Per TinyMCE documentation the language for Japanese is `ja` not `jp`.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/ui-localization/#supported-languages